# File Upload with KenoUI: provide URL via data- attribute

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-upload

We have a lot of similar file uploads, but they all upload to different urls with different parameters. And I'm trying to minimise amount of random javascript in our MVC4 application.  So I would like to provide a save url into kendo upload element via data-  parameter in html:

```
<input name="file" type="file" class="single-file-upload" data-saveurl="/some/path?entryId=2&productId=33" />
```

Url will be different in every instance. Sometimes we even have upload in a table and url will differ by a parameter (i.e. productId will be different).

Then in javascript I'm trying this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".single-file-upload").kendoUpload({
            multiple: false,
            async: {
                saveUrl: $(this).data('saveurl'),
                autoupload: false
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

But  this does not seem to work:  `$(this).data('saveurl')`
Data parameter is not picked up.. or rather `$(this)` is not what I would like it to be, hence the data attribute is empty, giving blank saveUrl property.

Andy idea how to access the object on which the `kendoUpload` is applied? Or some other method of specifying generic url on html element?

p.s. While writing this, noticed that this can be  done with [MVVM](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/upload/mvvm.html), but it has too much black magic for a simple thing, and would this work with many (50-100) uploads on the same page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate manually so that `this` is the DOM element you're creating the widget on:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".single-file-upload").each(function () {
        $(this).kendoUpload({
            multiple: false,
            async: {
                saveUrl: $(this).data('saveurl'),
                autoUpload: false
            }
        });
    });
});
```